# Kivy app not adjusting according to display size

Tags: python, kivy, window

I am creating a Kivy app. The app is fine on my 15-inch display but when I test it on a different sized display. The objects are not automatically adjusted. What do I do?

Comment: You should include your code in your question since your question is unclear and didn't point out the specific circumstance that you are having except you want a list of solutions ref to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The question are not so much clear but you can use kivy metrics visit https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.metrics.html and scale depends on what do you want Inches or Density-independent Pixels but i recommend the dp
you can call it by

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
```

and in kv file for example

```
size: '50dp' '50dp'
```

and by that you can have better automatically adjusted to whatever display size